# How to use grep when file does not contain the string

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

In my bash script I'm trying to print a line if a certain string does not exist in a file.

```
if grep -q "$user2" /etc/passwd; then
    echo "User does exist!!"
```

This is how I wrote it if I wanted the string to exist in the file but how can I change this to make it print "user does not exist" if the user is not found in the /etc/passwd file?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`grep` will return success if it finds at least one instance of the pattern and failure if it does not.  So you could either add an `else` clause if you want both "does" and "does not" prints, or you could just negate the `if` condition to only get failures.  An example of each:

```
if grep -q "$user2" /etc/passwd; then
    echo "User does exist!!"
else
    echo "User does not exist!!"
fi

if ! grep -q "$user2" /etc/passwd; then
    echo "User does not exist!!"
fi
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [grep option "-L / --files-without-match"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#OPTIONS), to check if file does not contain a string:

```
if [[ $(grep -L "$user2" /etc/passwd) ]]; then   
  echo "User does not exist!!"; 
fi
```

Comment: This answer is especially useful if you need a list of files in some directory that do not contain a given string, eg. `grep -L "important configuation property" configs/*`

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to look for the exit status of `grep`. For example:

```
grep -q "$user2" /etc/passwd
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "User does not exist!!"
```

If `grep` fails to find a match it will exit `1`, so `$?` will be `1`. `grep` will always return `0` if successful. So it is safer to use `$? != 0` than `$? == 1`.

Comment: this is really just a longer way of saying [what Eric said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223504/117549).

Comment: Well, for me the negative `if ! grep ...` statement did not work. So this is an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

```
grep -q query_text ./file.txt && echo true || echo false
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it with simple one liner:

```
for f in *.txt; do grep "tasks:" $f || echo $f; done
```

The command will check all files in the directory with txt extension and either write the search string (i.e. "tasks:") if found or else the name of the file.